# Rounding half down a decimal

Tags: c#, math, rounding

Does an equivalent of Java `RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN` exist in C#?

For example, I want to round `1.265` to `1.26`, and `1.266` to `1.27`.

If not, is there a simple way to do it?

Comment: @KayNelson: I did not vote, but one possible reason is because the question is impossible. 1.265 can be represented exactly in C# with the `decimal` literal `1.265m`, but `1.265` is a binary floating-point literal whose value is 1.26499998569488525390625, so the question of rounding a value that is exactly halfway between targets does not apply.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks for comment. That's someting I didn't know. Have you an idea of how i can get around the problem ?

Comment: @KBell: You would have to describe more about the complete problem. If you are reading decimal numerals from text and want to round them, then use `decimal` or character text, not `double`. If you are using `double`, you are using binary-based floating point and likely have a variety of round errors in arithmetic, so you would generally not expect exact decimal results at all.

Comment: Yes but that is still not a reason to downvote the question I would say :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at [Math.Round](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Math_Round_System_Double_System_Int32_System_MidpointRounding_) e.g.

```
  double[] tests = new double[] {
    1.265,
    1.266,
  };

  var demo = tests
    .Select(x => $"{x} -> {Math.Round(x, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)}");

  var report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, demo);

  Console.Write(report);
```

Outcome:

```
  1.265 -> 1.26
  1.266 -> 1.27
```

Comment: The `double` literal `1.265` does not have the value 1.265; it is 1.26499998569488525390625. So this code does not demonstrate that it performs the desired function.

Comment: It is impossible to represent `1.265` without precision loss: `1.265.ToString("R")`. Alas `1/10` is a periodical fraction in binary and that why `1.265 == 1 + 265 / 1000` can't be represented exactly

Comment: Yes, it is impossible. That is why the numbers in this answer fail to demonstrate whether `Round` rounds an exact midpoint as desired. You might instead use numbers that are possible, like 1.375 or 1.625.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `.Round` method with the following constructor overload:

```
public static double Round (double value, int digits, MidpointRounding mode);
```

Calling like so:

```
Math.Round(value, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

[Here's full documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Math_Round_System_Decimal_System_Int32_System_MidpointRounding_).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Math.Round`

```
    decimal d = Convert.ToDecimal("1.266");
    Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(d, 2));

    Console.ReadLine();
```